# Is possible to send message to msmq queue with electron?

Tags: angular, electron, msmq, sendmessage

i want to know if someone know how to send message to Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ) with electron.
I've found some npm packages like node-msmq but i cannot use with my node version, it works until node version 9 if i remember right.
Thaks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Updated-node-msmq works from Node.js 6x to 10x according to [their docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/updated-node-msmq).

```
npm install --save updated-node-msmq
```

Comment: i've tried updated-node-msmq but my node version is higher than version 10x and i cannot downgrade node in my project.